# Are email addresses ending with .com different from those ending with .com.[country_code]

Tags: email

I recently realiased a change of the email address of a someone I have been emailing for ages. Her email address used to be like `amy@company.com`. Now Gmail cannot deliver the email and the email address should be `amy@company.com.fr`. She said she never changed anything.

So, are these two email addresses different i..e can they co-exist? And why would it work before?

Answer (score 1):

The email addresses are different - unless the same company owns both domains and forwards them to the same accounts.